# Unable to use data from Socket.onmessage (HTML web sockets)

Tags: javascript, sockets, canvas, websocket

So, I have a javascript program that takes JSON data, and gets a string out of it. The string is a hex color code and it is used in canvas.fillStyle to draw a square that is colored the color that is sent via websocket in the JSON format, the thing is though, I can console.log(); the color code, but it doesn't work in canvas.fillStyle.

here is the code I am using:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    plots.onmessage = function (e) {
        ctx.fillStyle = JSON.parse(e.data).color;
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,10,10);
    };
```

Comment: Do you have the code to show?

Comment: @CraigRodrigues added it

Comment: I assume the hex code is coming back as a string? @EPICBRONY

Comment: @CraigRodrigues yep

Comment: Could you show the log of this hex color ?

Comment: It's just #FFFFFF, which is the right color @Kaiido

Comment: Could you try to create an [MCVE], we don't need to have the real socket working, you can replace it with a real JSON answer you got. There might be something you're doing on your context that breaks things up.

Comment: @Kaiido I've recreated it without the socket, and it works, so I would appear that it is a problem with plots.onmessage or something